# Can loss sharing ratio of all the partners in the LLP be kept 0%?

Tags: tax-law, corporate-law, partnership

L.L.P. stands for Limited Liability Partnership.
Profit and Loss sharing ratio & relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

> Can loss sharing ratio of all the partners in the LLP be kept 0%?

No.

The profit and loss sharing ratio of all of the partners combined (for tax purposes) needs to add up to 100% of the profits and losses in every tax year.